# How to create Company Organogram Using Jquery ECOTree or Treant-js With PHP & MySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree

i am working with ECOTree and Treants-js for Company Evaluation Tree

1. i fail to increase a specific node when i am going to increase a
   node it effect every node.
2. how to increase or decrease specific sub-tree's path.
3. how to increase or decrease specific Node's sibling    separation.
4. how to increase or decrease specific Node's Level Separation.
5. when to sibling stay along if i increase a sibling
   path height it overlap to another sibling.
6. when tree open with huge amount of data and node's path height is increased or decreased one node goes overlap to an other node.
   for details and clear information image and project link given below.

Reference link:

ECOTree:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16192/Graphic-JavaScript-Tree-with-Layout

http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

http://www.voidcn.com/blog/flash8627/article/p-949947.html

SpaceTree:

http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.code.html
http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

Treant-js:

http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/

https://github.com/fperucic/treant-js

Problem Image :

1. Normal with out increase height.
2. When increase height.
   [image]

[image]

**Project link:**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B75Il8ylWQNiOFVPREpCS1NIc0E